# In which case can I use lookforward/lookbehind and non capturing group for a fixed-length string?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I am writting a grammar syntax theme for Atom and I don't get the difference and when I need to use `lookforward/lookbehind` instead of `non-capturing group`.

For example I want to get `option` in this string : `first (secondfixedword option)`.

- `(?:\(secondfixedword\s+)([a-zA-Z1-9]+)(?:\))` I will match `(secondfixedword option)` but the captured group will be only `option`.
- `(?<=\(secondfixedword)(?:\s*)([a-zA-Z1-9]+)(?=\))` I'll capture only `option`. (With the spaces behind since I cannot use `lookbehind` with not-fixed length)

Sometimes `lookbehind` is not supported, then how can I do ?

I see the difference between `matching`, `capturing` and `non capturing` groups but for me, we can simulate the same behavior as `lookbehind` and `lookforward` with just `non capturing group`.

I would like to match `value` in `if (value)` or `if ( value )` or `if    (   value )`. With a lot of spaces or not.

Thank you.

Comment: In Atom grammar definitions, you can use lookbehind with a fixed length pattern in all cases where you only need to check for some text presence/absence, but not include it in the match.

Comment: How to simulate the same behavior with a non-fixed length ? For now, I used `include` but with a lot of `instances`, it's quickly hard.